# change app name in current time

Tags: iphone, ipad

is it possible to change app name through code in run time 
if possible plz reply fast.
I am using this code
`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
           NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


           NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SelectedImages.plist"];

           if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs])
           {
               NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
               NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
          [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:myPathDocs error:NULL];



               NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myPathDocs];

               //dic = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
               NSMutableArray *arr =[dic objectForKey:@"CFBundleIconFiles"];          
               NSLog(@"Number of items %d",[arr count]);
               NSLog(@"object %@",[arr objectAtIndex:0]);
               [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Icon.png"];
                 NSLog(@"object %@",[arr objectAtIndex:0]);
               [arr writeToFile:myPathDocs atomically:YES] ;

               [NSBundle bundleWithPath:myPathDocs];

               //[[NSBundle mainBundle]setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dic];
                [arr release]; 
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have looks like it is trying to change the icon, not the name. Either one of them is not possible on a non-jailbroken phone AFAIK. You can't edit the bundle of an existing app.

Comment: You are correct, application bundles are read only. Thus you can't edit them